How to perform Dynamic Task Mapping at the TaskGroup level in Airflow using Operators?
Body:
I am trying to implement dynamic task mapping in Apache Airflow using a TaskGroup that includes operators like SQLCheckOperator and SQLExecuteQueryOperator. I have managed to use dynamic task mapping at the individual task level within the group, but I am unsure how to achieve dynamic task mapping directly at the TaskGroup level.
Here’s a working example with dynamic task mapping for individual tasks:
with TaskGroup('check_group') as check:
    t1 = SQLCheckOperator.partial(
        task_id='check1',
        sql='SELECT count(*)> 0 FROM data_table WHERE id = {{ task.parameters["id"] }}'
    ).expand(parameters=task_id.output)

    t2 = SQLExecuteQueryOperator.partial(
        task_id='update1',
        map_index_template="{{ task.parameters['id'] }}",
        sql='''UPDATE table SET date = NOW() WHERE id = {{ task.parameters["id"] }} '''
    ).expand(parameters=task_id.output)

I also have a working task like this that fetches the data dynamically for task_id:
task_id = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id='scope', 
    sql='''SELECT DISTINCT id FROM idtable''',
    handler=lambda x: [dict(zip(['id'], row)) for row in fetch_all_handler(x)]
)

This works fine, and I am able to perform dynamic task mapping at the task level for each task in the group.
The Problem:
I want to implement dynamic task mapping at the TaskGroup level, similar to the example below using the @task_group decorator:
@task_group(group_id="group1")
def tg1(my_num):
    @task
    def print_num(num):
        return num

    @task
    def add_42(num):
        return num + 42

    print_num(my_num) >> add_42(my_num)

# Creating 6 mapped task group instances of the task group group1
tg1_object = tg1.expand(my_num=[19, 23, 42, 8, 7, 108])

In this example, I can achieve dynamic task mapping by passing values to the @task-decorated tasks, but I am unable to replicate this directly using operators like SQLCheckOperator or SQLExecuteQueryOperator within a TaskGroup.
So, for example, code like this doesn't work, but corresponds to my idea of dynamic task mapping in a group with an operator inside. So, for example, code like this doesn't work, but corresponds to my idea of dynamic task mapping in a group with an operator inside.

def get_scope() -> SQLExecuteQueryOperator:
    return SQLExecuteQueryOperator(task_id='scope', sql='''SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table''', handler=lambda x: [dict(zip(['id'], row)) for row in fetch_all_handler(x)])

@task_group(group_id="group1")
def tg1(id):
    # Task 1: Check if the condition is met
    def check1(id):
        return SQLCheckOperator(
            task_id='check1',
            sql='SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM data_table WHERE id = {{ task.parameters["id"] }}'
        )

    # Task 2: Update the table if condition is met
    def update1(id):
        return SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
            task_id='update1',
            map_index_template="{{ task.parameters['id'] }}",
            sql='''UPDATE table SET date = NOW() WHERE id = {{ task.parameters["id"] }}'''
        )
    
    # Set task dependencies
    check1(id) >> update1(id)

# Create 6 instances of the task group group1 with dynamic task mapping
task1 = get_scope()
tg1_object = tg1.expand(id=task1.output)

I got this error when I tried this solution
MappedArgument(_input=ListOfDictsExpandInput(value=XComArg(<Task(SQLExecuteQueryOperator): task_id >)), _key='id')'

Question:
How can I achieve dynamic task mapping at the TaskGroup level using operators (instead of the @task decorator)? Is it possible to use expand() or another mechanism to achieve this behavior directly within a TaskGroup?
I would like to avoid as much as possible using a loop.
I want to find a solution to my probleme which is to find a way to create a dynamic task mapping for a task group with operator inside

Nested operators are recommended against and log a warning when used.
It is important to bear in mind that the future direction is to throw exceptions when operators are nested this way.
If you implement a nested operator that executes your SQL, this could work as a stopgap.
    @task_group(group_id="group1")
    def tg1(id):
        # Task 1: Check if the condition is met
        @task
        def check1(id, **context):
            expanded_params = {"id": id}
            context["params"] = expanded_params
            operator = SQLCheckOperator(
                task_id='check1',
                sql='SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM data_table WHERE id = {{ params.id }}',
                conn_id="default")
            operator.render_template_fields(context=context)
            return operator.execute(context=context)

        # Task 2: Update the table if condition is met
        @task
        def update1(id, **context):
            expanded_params = {"id": id}
            context["params"] = expanded_params
            operator = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
                task_id='update1',
                sql='''UPDATE table SET date = NOW() WHERE id = {{ params.id }}''',
                conn_id="default")
            operator.render_template_fields(context=context)
            return operator.execute(context=context)

        
        # Set task dependencies
        check1(id) >> update1(id)

    # Create 6 instances of the task group group1 with dynamic task mapping
    tg1.expand(id=[19, 23, 42, 8, 7, 108])

Bearing this in mind, I found it more convenient to execute the SQL operators directly by explicitly resolving the value from the MappedArgument passed from the task group for the task instance.
from airflow.decorators import dag, task_group
from airflow.providers.common.sql.operators.sql import (
    SQLCheckOperator, SQLExecuteQueryOperator
)

import pendulum

default_args = {
    "owner": "Oluwafemi Sule",
}

@dag(
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="0 0 * * *",  # Cron schedule
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 12, 4, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    owner_links={
        "Oluwafemi Sule": "https://github.com/osule/astronomer-experiments",
    },
)
def expand_tasks_sql_orig():
    @task_group(group_id="group1")
    def tg1(id):
        # Task 1: Check if the condition is met
        expanded_params = {"id": id}
        check1 = SQLCheckOperator(
            task_id='check1',
            sql='SELECT count(*) > 0 FROM data_table WHERE id = {{ params.id.resolve({"ti": ti, "run_id": run_id}) }}',
            params=expanded_params,
            conn_id="!!TODO: Set this"
        )

        # Task 2: Update the table if condition is met
        update1 = SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
            task_id='update1',
            sql='''UPDATE table SET date = NOW() WHERE id = {{ params.id.resolve({"ti": ti, "run_id": run_id}) }}''',
            params=expanded_params,
            conn_id="!!TODO: Set this"
        )
        
        # Set task dependencies
        check1 >> update1

    # Create 6 instances of the task group group1 with dynamic task mapping
    tg1.expand(id=[19, 23, 42, 8, 7, 108])

dag_obj = expand_tasks_sql_orig()


Yes, I agree with you, and therein lies the problem. How do you avoid nested operators by using expand on a non-explicitly resolved list of values?
